How to add and access user specific data in firebase using swiftui
So im building an app where im storing a list of exercises that a user selects into a firestore database. However, currently whenever every user has access to all the workouts made. I want to make it so that an user only has access to the workouts they have made? How would that be possible?
I have tried finding a solution to this online but i can not find anything about it.

You'll want to implement this by combining a Firestore query, and Firebase security rules. The query ensures that you only request the data for the current user, and the security rules then ensure that only this request is allowed (so that a malicious user can no longer request data from all users).
A good starting point is this example from the documentation on content owner-only data access, which for Firestore could work with these security rules (if you store the workouts for each user in a separate collection named after the UID of that user):
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /some_collection/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}

If you use a different data model, you'll need to modify these rules for that.
